# Не открывается новое окно

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

```
public partial class App
{
    public App()
    {
        if (Settings.Default.localPort == 0 || Settings.Default.remotePort == 0 ||
            Settings.Default.ip == "no_ip")
        {
            SettingsView settingsView = new SettingsView();
            settingsView.ShowDialog();

            ProgramInfo.Create(Settings.Default.localPort,
                Settings.Default.remotePort, Settings.Default.ip);
        }

        ProgramInfo.Create(Settings.Default.localPort,
                Settings.Default.remotePort, Settings.Default.ip);

        MainView mainView = new MainView();
        mainView.Show();
    }
}
```

Если значения параметров нулевые - запускается окно настроек, где должен их ввести (сохранения настроек проихводится в `SettingsViewModel`). Проблема: не запускается окно `mainView`, хотя конструктор `MainViewModel` срабатывает, но после просто программа закрывается, никаких ошибок - ничего. Если настройки уже введены (то есть окно настроек не открывается), то `mainView` открывается и всё работает как надо.

Comment: Что такое `App`? Наследник `Application`?

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего у вас просто сетается главным окно `SettingsView` и после его закрытия стопается программа.

К слову, прочитайте про [`Application.Startup`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.startup(v=vs.110).aspx).

Попробуйте так:

```
public partial class App
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        var shouldShowSettings = Settings.Default.localPort == 0
            || Settings.Default.remotePort == 0
            || Settings.Default.ip == "no_ip";

        MainView mainView = new MainView
        {
            ShowInTaskbar = !shouldShowSettings,
            Visibility = shouldShowSettings ? Visibility.Hidden : Visibility.Visible
        };
        mainView.Show();

        if (shouldShowSettings)
        {
            SettingsView settingsView = new SettingsView();
            settingsView.ShowDialog();

            mainView.ShowInTaskbar = true;
            mainView.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }

        ProgramInfo.Create(Settings.Default.localPort,
            Settings.Default.remotePort, Settings.Default.ip);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, проблема в том, что вы пытаетесь открыть диалог в конструкторе `App`. Приложение будет «запущено» после того, как объект будет сконструирован.

Попробуйте перенести логику с окнами в `OnStartup`.

И не забудьте переключить `ShutdownMode` в `OnExplicitShutdown`. И на закрытии главного окна таки вызвать `Shutdown`.

Comment: Или явно задать MainWindow и переключить  ShutdownMode 
 в OnMainWindowClose. Точнее, сначала выставить его в OnExplicitShutdown, а потом - в OnMainWindowClose.